# SSIS package to to pick up remote files and process to local DB

Tags: file, variables, parameters, ssis

I'm new to SSIS and need to transfer a number of files from a remote server location into a local DB using an SSIS package.The files are in the format of YYYYMMDDfilename.txt so I need to use parameters to pass through the dates and files paths i believe. What are the steps needed to do so?

Comment: Google for tutorials and learn SSIS.  The rest will be easy after that.

Answer (score 0):

There's some missing details in your question, but it sounds like you need to dynamically transfer files based on the YYYYMMDD date format incorporated as part of the file names.  And the date is somehow relevant to the date in which the SSIS package is run.  There a various approaches to this, but I'll give you the one that is fairly straight forward and modular gathering files based on the current date.  I am using BIDS 2008R2.

1. Create a variable called RunDate_YYYYMMDD (data type of String).
2. Go to the Properties for variable RunDate_YYYYMMDD, set the EvaluateAsExpression to True and enter the following for the expression:

   (DT_STR, 4, 1252) DATEPART("yyyy" , GETDATE()) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("mm" , GETDATE()), 2) + RIGHT("0" + (DT_STR, 2, 1252) DATEPART("dd" , GETDATE()), 2)

> This provides a string value in the format of YYYYMMDD that will be
>   applied as a wildcard.

After this you can then add a script task and pass to it the RunDate_YYYYMMDD variable as read only.  This can then be applied as a wildcard and copying only the files you need using C# like that shown in the following link: [Copy Files with script task](http://pranavkumarsql.blogspot.com/2013/10/ssis-script-task-to-copy-files-from-one.html)

Under the Public Void Main part you'll need to define a local variable using your DTS RunDate_YYYYMMDD variable.  For example:

string RunDate = DTS.Variables["User::RunDate_YYYYMMDD"].Value.ToString();

The local RunDate variable would then be applied in the file comparisons below to determine which files to copy.

Hope this helps.